# Прокси и кеш - как убедиться что запись актуальна?

Tags: c#, proxy

Добавляю в программу поддержку прокси.

Для пользователя добавляю возможность при указании настроек проверить, работает ли прокси. Код проверки вроде тупой и элементарный:

```
  try
  {
    var selected = model.SelectedProxySettingModel;
    var address = model.TestAddress;

    var proxy = new WebProxy(selected.Address, false, null, new NetworkCredential(selected.UserName, selected.Password));
    var client = new WebClient() { Proxy = proxy };
    await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(true);
    Dialogs.ShowInfo("Проверка прокси", "Успешно.");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Dialogs.ShowInfo("Проверка прокси", "Произошла ошибка. \r\n" + e.Message);
  }
```

Проверяю в клиенте как это работает и нахожу смущающую меня вещь:

1. Вбиваю адрес для тестирования например сам SO - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20intags%3amine
2. Вбиваю неверный логин или пароль, мне ожидаемо возвращает 407
3. Вбиваю верные данные, страница успешно скачивается, код сообщает что всё хорошо.
4. Меняю логин на неправильный - проверка всё равно проходит.

Я посмотрел в отладке - неправильный логин заносится во все нужные свойства, класс прокси с некорректными данными уходит в вебклиент - а страничка сообщает, что скачалась успешно.

Есть подозрение, что это как то зависит от сайта. Потому что google например ведёт себя аналогично, а некоторые рандомные сайты таки дают при такой проверке ошибку, как я и ожидаю.

Посмотрел логи прокси - там обращений к stackoverflow после успешного нет в логах. Если прокси не врёт, то через неё никаких запросов не делается в такой ситуации.

Вопрос - как сделать проверку гарантированной, чтобы нельзя было случайно ошибиться?

ПС: проверяю это сейчас на Windows. Позже буду проверять на Linux и MacOS, так что если есть какие то особенности на разных ОС - пишите тоже, пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть на запросы с помощью fiddler. Возможно, веб сервер добавляет заголовки кеширования см. https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers.

Кеширование на клиенте отключается так

```cs
webClient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403130/webclient-downloadstring-returning-old-data

Comment: Заголовки есть, настройка не помогает. За попытку - спасибо =)